# Github Pages is generating my site in a different way than it did previously

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I wrote a loop in Jekyll to populate rows of four columns. The last row will have one to four columns filled. In local development it works as expected. On Github Pages it has worked for the last two years. I haven't changed this code in over a year. Every time I push new changes to Github Pages, the static site generator kicks in and rebuilds the entire site. At some point, the code below stopped writing in columns and started writing in rows only with a single column filled. Again, I didn't change the source file, so apparently somewhere in maintenance on Github's side something has changed to the point of breaking this layout.

Did Jekyll or Github Pages change in such a way that the below code is now broken or outdated? Do you see anything I can change to get the previous result restored?

```
---
layout: default
---
<div id="people-container" class="container">

  {% assign numColumns = 4 %}
  {% assign columnWidth = 12 | divided_by: numColumns %}
  {% for person in site.data.people %}
    {% assign card = person[1] %}

    {% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', nil, nil, nil %}
      {% if card.image %}
        {% if card.profile == true %}
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/team/{{ person[0] }}/">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="col-sm-{{columnWidth}}">
          <div class="profile-image-wrapper">
            <img class="profile-image" src="{{ site.baseurl}}/{{ card.image }}" alt="{{ person[1].name }}">
          </div>
          <div class="profile-data-wrapper inverted">
            <p class="profile-name">{{ card.name }}</p>
            <p class="profile-title">{{ card.title }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% if card.profile == true %}
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% cycle 'end row' : nil, nil, nil, '</div>' %}

  {% endfor %}
  {% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>', '</div>', '</div>' %}

</div>
```

What I had before:

[image]

What I have now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github pages (and Jekyll) now uses `Liquid 4.0.0`, which doesn't handle `nil` in the `cycle` tag (as you are using it to generate columns).

There is an open issue in Liquid repo: [Since 4.0.0 'nil' values are ignored inside cycle tag](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/922).

Suggested patch meanwhile: changing `nil` to an empty string `''`.

```
    {% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', '', '', '' %}
```